# Dynamically update the @value annotated fields in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to dynamically update the `@value` annotated fields in my application.

First of all, this application has a custom property source, with source being a `Map<Object, String>`.
A **timer** is enabled to update the values after a minute interval.

```
package com.test.dynamic.config;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.core.env.EnumerablePropertySource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

public class CustomPropertySorce extends EnumerablePropertySource<Map<String, Object>> {

    public CustomPropertySorce(String name, Map<String, Object> source) {
        super(name, source);
        
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                source.put("prop1", "yoyo-modified");
                source.put("prop2", new Date().getTime());
                System.out.println("Updated Source :" + source);
            }
        }, 60000);
    }

    

    
    @Override
    public String[] getPropertyNames() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return StringUtils.toStringArray(this.source.keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.source.get(name);
    }

}
```

Initial values of source `Map<String, Object>` is supplied from the `PropertySourceLocator`. (This is not the real scenario, but I am trying to recreate the logic used here)

```
package com.test.dynamic.config;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

public class CustomPropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {


    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {

        Map<String, Object> source=new HashMap<String,Object>(){{put("prop1","yoyo");put("prop2",new Date().getTime());}};
        return new CustomPropertySorce("custom_source",source);
    }

}
```

`RestController` class where I inject these properties using `@Value` is given below.
`environment.getProperty("prop1");` is supplying updated value, but not the `@value` annotated fields.
I also tried to inject a new property source `updatedMap` using the `addFirst` method of `environment.propertySources()` assuming that it will take precedence over the others. But that effort also went futile. any clue is much appreciated.

```
package com.test.dynamic.config.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DataController {
    
    @Value("${prop1}")
    private String propertyOne;
    
    @Value("${prop2}")
    private Long propertyTwo;
    
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;
    
    @GetMapping("/p1")
    private String getProp1() {
        System.out.println("~~~~>"+environment.getPropertySources());
        
        environment.getPropertySources().forEach(ps -> {
            if(ps.containsProperty("prop1") || ps.containsProperty("prop2")) {
                System.out.println("*******************************************************");
                System.out.println(ps.getName());
                System.out.println(ps.getProperty("prop1"));
                System.out.println(ps.getProperty("prop2"));
                System.out.println("*******************************************************");
            }
        });
        
        
        
//      env.get
        return propertyOne;
//      return environment.getProperty("prop1");
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/p2")
    private Long getProp2() {
        System.out.println("~~~~>"+environment.getPropertySources());
        
        
        
//      env.get
        return propertyTwo;
//      return environment.getProperty("prop1");
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/update")
    public String updateProperty() {
        Map<String, Object> updatedProperties = new HashMap<>();
        updatedProperties.put("prop1", "Property one modified");
        MapPropertySource mapPropSource = new MapPropertySource("updatedMap", updatedProperties);
        
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(mapPropSource);
        
        return environment.getPropertySources().toString();
    }

}
```

If you think this is not the right way of injecting values to a `RestController`, please let me know. All possible alternate suggestions/best practices are accepted.

Comment: Take a look at `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference`. I don't have time to type an example as an answer but I've used it to share a reference to a `Map` that had changing values.

Comment: You can also [reload all properties](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties#reloading-cloud) using the actuator and the cloud. For this there is the annotation `@RefreshScope`.

Comment: @flaxel I am creating a library. Hence I do not have control over the scope of the bean where the property is injected.  RefreshScope says  "Spring Cloud also has introduced RefreshScope, and we can use it for configuration classes or beans. As a result, the default scope will be refresh instead of singleton."

Comment: @Paul did you mean to wrap the "Map<String, Object> source" inside an atomic reference? I am wondering how will that help when the "environment" which is responsible to holding the values itself is showing the updated value.

Comment: I tried AtomicReference.... Map<String, Object> initialSource = new HashMap<>();
  initialSource.put("prop1","yoyo");
  initialSource.put("prop2",new Date().getTime());
  AtomicReference<Map<String, Object>> source = new AtomicReference<>();
  source.set(initialSource);

but did not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you `@flaxel`. I used `@RefreshScope` to resolve this issue.
Posting the solution here if it helps someone with the same query.

In this particular case, I applied `@RefreshScope` on my Controller to refresh the bean with new values.

[You can refer to this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/spring-cloud-config-server-and-good-practice-of-refresh-scope-usage-ef65d0fee379) link before applying `@RefreshScope` to your bean.

It is the spring boot actuator that facilitates this refresh mechanism. So in order for this to work, you must have actuator in your classpath.

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: "${springboot_version}"
```

Then as discussed earlier, add `RefreshScope` to the bean that needs to be refreshed.

Finally, invoke the `actuator/refresh` endpoint to trigger the refresh.

If you want to programmatically do it, **Autowire** an instance of `RefreshEndpoint` class to your bean and invoke the `refresh()` method in it.
[Note: You don’t have to strictly follow this approach, but I am giving a clue that it can be Autowired]

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class DataController {
  @Value("${prop1}")
private String prop1;

@Autowired
private RefreshEndpoint refreshEndpoint;

@GetMapping("/p1")
public String getProp1(){
return prop1;
}

@getMappig("/refresh")
public void refresh(){
 refreshEndpoint.refresh();
}

}
```

**************** MORE (if you are developing a library) ********************

What if you are developing a library and you have to get the `RefreshEndpoint`  instance from the current `ApplicationContext`?

Simply Autowiring `RefreshEndpoint` may give you a null reference. Instead, you can get hold of the current `ApplicationContext` by the method given below. And use the `ApplicationContext` to get the `RefreshEndpoint` instance to invoke the `refresh()` method on it.

```
public class LocalApplicationContextFetcher implements
        ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    
    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ctx = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }


    public static void refresh(){
      ctx.getBean(RefreshEndpoint.class).refresh();
    }
    

}
```

Finally, add this class to the `spring.factories` to get invoked by spring.

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
com.x.y.z.LocalApplicationContextFetcher
```