# Dynamically update yml @values

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I tried to dynamically update the `example.key`. I can do using `ConfigurationProperties`. But is it possible to update the key string (`@Value("${example.key}")`) on the fly without touching the yml file. Because its declared in many places and I do want to update it in all the classes.

**application.yml**

```
example:
 key: "value"
```

**ExampleController.java**

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="example")
public class ExampleController {
    private String key;
}
```

**ExampleClass.java**

```
@Component
public class ExampleClass {

    @Value("${example.key}")
    private String key;

    @Autowired
    ExampleController exampleController;

    public void configTest(String value) {
         exampleController.setKey(value);
         System.out.println("Result: " + key + ":" + exampleController.getKey());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
configTest("newValue");

Result: value : newValue

Expected Result: newValue : newValue
```

Comment: You need to use @RefreshScope. Also there is another topic regarding your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100539/dynamically-update-the-value-annotated-fields-in-spring

Comment: is there any alternative other than @RefreshScope?